# Insert...on duplicate key update in other databases(ParAccel) except MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

Insert...on duplicate key update in MySql is not a sql standard. Can we treat this statement as atomic?
Is there any equivalent statements in other databases especially ParAccel?
If no,considering atomic or performance,how to design the statement by using  sql92 sql99 or other standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close equivalent in Standard SQL is [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29), introduced in SQL-99 and altered slightly in SQL:2003.

`MERGE` is widely supported e.g. SQL Server 2008, Oracle 9, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Thanks. MERGE works, but I found there's no merge in paraccel. So i use transactions.